fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD'
I am trying to clone a git repository from the gerrit system, but I encounter an error given below.
$ git clone ssh://gerrit.codereview.com:29418/repo/abc
Cloning into 'abc'...
remote: Counting objects: 109851, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (23/23)
remote: Total 176120 (delta 0), reused 176113 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (176120/176120), 7.08 GiB | 30.43 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (70343/70343), done.
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update ref 'refs/heads/master': trying to write non-commit object ad3b40d1b582c561edd8a754d029db608f14a98c to branch 'refs/heads/master'

This issue persists across multiple systems. Can you please suggest a solution?

Check if somenthing gone wrong with git reflog

From gerrit server side git reflog didn't return anything.

after the clone - is it possible to call git commands in the abc folder, like git fetch, git checkout?

@laplasz clone in between it fails with above errors. So after that no abc repository folder available in my local path.

This error could be due to master branch corruption; you could try downloading a different branch, like this:
git clone ssh://gerrit.codereview.com:29418/repo/abc --branch another-branch
and if download will be successful - you can investigate what happens with the master.

Our overseas Gerrit support team has resolved the issue. They explained that this is a mirrored repository, and the partner company had created an annotated tag and overwritten the master branch with it. As a result, users were unable to clone the repository. To fix this on the mirrored site, our support team set the commit directly in the master branch instead of using the tag, and the cloning issue was resolved.
However, our team has informed us that partner that the issue needs to be fixed on their repository to prevent similar problems in the future.
